# Why view is not changing

Tags: iphone

I am trying to navigate from old view to new view. But the view does not navigate.
Here is my code.

```
DetailsList *detailViewController = [[DetailsList alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsList" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an NavigationController or any other?

Comment: i am using navigation controller.

Comment: DetailsList *detailViewController = [[DetailsList alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsList" bundle:[NSBundle MainBundle]]; try this

Comment: I tried it. But still not changing the view.

Comment: code called at button click ???

Comment: no this code is not called at button click. Is it only possible at button click ????

Comment: no i didn't mean that...

Comment: No I am not getting any error.

Comment: then its a damn interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set the break point at 
   `DetailsList *detailViewController = [[DetailsList alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsList" bundle:nil];` line.
2. When debug point comes at `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];` line then, put ur mouse cursor on "detailViewController " variable, and check does it shows any hex values. If it shows (x0x) it means memory is not allocated .

Comment: it should be 0x0 and also check if the same for navigation controller

Comment: @Dimple : No it should not be x0x. The value must be other then x0x so it means memory is allocated to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check few things like ....

1. are these line of code executed ..
2. are u getting `detailViewController`
3. do your self (vc) has a navigationController

If all these are good then its hard to imagine cause ...because code here just looks fine.

Comment: I checked all the options, everything is fine. One thing i will mention here is, these lines of code are not set at the click of button. But does that make any difference ?

Comment: no it doesn't make any difference... but if button is there then u should check the IB any method call...

Answer (score 0):

check if this code is exectuted at all. Maybe the reason is somewhere else eg. in connections with a button and suchlike